# Apache .htaccess: do not redirect if

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, regex, apache2

I'm struggling to find out how to perform the following redirection via `.htaccess` and it's driving me a bit crazy.

**Scenario:**

If requests points to one of the following paths, do not perform any redirection:

- `/`
- `/#/`
- `/#/admin`
- `/#/auth`

Otherwise, point the requests to `/viewer` and preserve any provided parameters.

**Example:**

- `example.com/` should not be redirected.
- `example.com/#/admin/` should not be redirected.
- `example.com/#/Qsj7jw` should be redirected to `example.com/viewer/Qsj7jw`.

Answer (score 0):

> `example.com/#/Qsj7jw` should be redirected to `example.com/viewer/Qsj7jw`.

Basically, you can't do this type of redirection server-side in `.htaccess`.

The *fragment identifier* (ie. everything after the `#`) is not even sent to the server (the browser strips it from the request), so the server (ie. `.htaccess`) only ever sees `example.com/` in the above request.

Fragment identifiers are used solely for client-side manipulation/navigation. eg. with JavaScript.